# Google charts linechart showing only a dot instead of a line when using JSON input

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

I am trying to populate my line chart with data from JSON.

This is what it should look like: https://jsfiddle.net/ud5y3m3y/

Now when I switch to JSON it gives me only a dot on the chart: https://jsfiddle.net/5at6w6en/

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

          var JSONinput = {"rows":[{"c":[{"v":[13,26,15]},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":[13,26,45]},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":[13,27,15]},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":[13,27,45]},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":[13,28,15]},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0}]}],"cols":[{"id":"","label":"Time of Day","type":"timeofday"},{"id":"","label":"Somevalue 1","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"Somevalue 2","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"Somevalue 3","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"Somevalue 4","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"Somevalue 5","type":"number"}]};


        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(JSONinput);


        var options = {
          title: 'History of somevalues',
          width: 900,
          height: 500,
          hAxis: {
            format: 'HH:mm:ss',
            gridlines: {count: 15}
          },
          vAxis: {
            gridlines: {color: 'none'},
            minValue: 0,
            viewWindowMode: "explicit",
            viewWindow: {min: 0}
          }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);

      }
```

I have read this already https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes

And this
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference

But haven't been able to figure out what is the problem. Usually the dot problem arises when there is some kind of typo in the input to datatable.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Ahaa! There is a problem with the JSON. it is missing "c" array after the first "c" array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my bad!

The code that was generating JSON was buggy.

It was not adding the "c" array to each row.

This is the correct JSON

```
{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Time of Day","type":"timeofday"},
        {"id":"","label":"Somevalue 1","type":"number"},
        {"id":"","label":"Somevalue 2","type":"number"},
        {"id":"","label":"Somevalue 3","type":"number"},
        {"id":"","label":"Somevalue 4","type":"number"},
        {"id":"","label":"Somevalue 5","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":[13,26,15]},{"v":10},{"v":20},{"v":30},{"v":40},{"v":50}]},
        {"c":[{"v":[13,26,45]},{"v":10},{"v":200},{"v":300},{"v":400},{"v":500}]},
        {"c":[{"v":[13,27,15]},{"v":30},{"v":20},{"v":70},{"v":40},{"v":60}]},
        {"c":[{"v":[13,27,45]},{"v":10},{"v":70},{"v":60},{"v":40},{"v":80}]},
        {"c":[{"v":[13,28,15]},{"v":50},{"v":60},{"v":60},{"v":70},{"v":50}]}
      ]
}
```